# Help with Redis-Sharp or ServiceStack.Redis 

Tags: c#, redis

I tried to run Redis-Sharp test program. It sets the string length when I set some key,value (both strings). And while reading the data it throws exception.
      I then moved on and tried ServiceStack.Redis and after adding library reference it properly shows the properties of RedisClient etc but when I try to build it throws an error no library reference found. Can anyone help me get past this step and actually see some test programs running proper commands on Redis server ?

Regards,
Lalith

Comment: I know this thread is a bit old, but I've hit the same problem and I am completely baffled.  Downloaded Redis-Sharp and it won't even pass its own tests.  Fails utterly in a simple three line test (connect, write a key, read a key).  Booksleeve, etc work fine, but I wanted to drop back to the most basic for (other) project compatability reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a new project is created in Visual Studio 2010 the Target framework (on Application tab of project properties) is set to **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile**; changing this to **.NET Framework 4** resolves the RedisClient build problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of the ServiceStack.Redis client - can I ask which build are you having problems with? i.e. what build references were you missing?

I've currently in the process of moving to GitHub (which is now the official project site of the open source project).

So from now on the latest source code and binary releases will be available here:
https://github.com/mythz/ServiceStack.Redis

In GitHub the Redis Client is now a self-contained, top-level project so you should be able to build without any problems.

Older binary releases (and source code) should still be available from the old project site:
http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/ServiceStackRedis

Hope this helps,

-Demis

Comment: Using v2.0.50727 downloaded yesterday I do the folllowing in LINQPad; reference ServiceStack.Redis.dll and ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll; add namespace import for ServiceStack.Redis and I'm able to build and run no problem. Do exactly the same in Visual Studio with the same code and I get "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'RedisClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\stevec\Documents\My Dropbox\Projects\RedisTest\Program.cs 13 33 RedisTest" when I build.

Comment: Hi, The only dependencies the Redis client has is: ServiceStack.Common.dll, ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll and ServiceStack.Text.dll - other than that it's just a standard managed .NET dll, that should run everywhere: no PInvokes, Reflection.Emit, etc

Comment: Have found the solution and posted the answer.

Comment: Awesome job with ServiceStack - one of the very best stacks I've had the pleasure of using!